# Android one to one chat Firebase

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to make one to one chat app and I have firebase database with childs(receiver_sender). I use FirebaseRecyclerAdapter to show a messages, but it doesn't work. Sending messages to firebase is working, but receiving and showing messages doesn't work. Can anybody can help?

here's my code:

```
public class MessageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_message);


        room_type_1 = recipiant + "_" + sender;
        room_type_2 = sender + "_" + recipiant;


        // New child entries
        mFirebaseDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("messages");


        mFirebaseDatabaseReference
                .getRef()
                .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        if (dataSnapshot.hasChild(room_type_1)) {

                            listFirebase(room_type_1);

                        } else if (dataSnapshot.hasChild(room_type_2)) {
                            listFirebase(room_type_2);

                        } else {
                            Log.e(TAG, "getMessageFromFirebaseUser: no such room available");
                        }


                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                        // Unable to get message
                    }
                });





    public void listFirebase(String room){

        mFirebaseAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<FriendlyMessage,MessageViewHolder>(
                FriendlyMessage.class,
                R.layout.item_message,
                MessageViewHolder.class,
                mFirebaseDatabaseReference.child(room)) {

            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(final MessageViewHolder viewHolder,
                                              FriendlyMessage friendlyMessage, int position) {
                mProgressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.INVISIBLE);
                if (friendlyMessage.getText() != null) {
                    viewHolder.messageTextView.setText(friendlyMessage.getText());
                    viewHolder.messageTextView.setVisibility(TextView.VISIBLE);
                    viewHolder.messageImageView.setVisibility(ImageView.GONE);
                } else {
                    String imageUrl = friendlyMessage.getImageUrl();
                    if (imageUrl.startsWith("gs://")) {
                        StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl(imageUrl);
                        storageReference.getDownloadUrl().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    String downloadUrl = task.getResult().toString();
                                    Glide.with(viewHolder.messageImageView.getContext())
                                            .load(downloadUrl)
                                            .into(viewHolder.messageImageView);
                                } else {
                                    Log.w(TAG, "Getting download url was not successful.",
                                            task.getException());
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        Glide.with(viewHolder.messageImageView.getContext())
                                .load(friendlyMessage.getImageUrl())
                                .into(viewHolder.messageImageView);
                    }
                    viewHolder.messageImageView.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
                    viewHolder.messageTextView.setVisibility(TextView.GONE);
                }


                viewHolder.messengerTextView.setText(friendlyMessage.getName());
                if (friendlyMessage.getPhotoUrl() == null) {
                    viewHolder.messengerImageView.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(MessageActivity.this,
                            R.drawable.ic_account_circle_black_36dp));
                } else {
                    Glide.with(MessageActivity.this)
                            .load(friendlyMessage.getPhotoUrl())
                            .into(viewHolder.messengerImageView);
                }

            }
        };
        mFirebaseAdapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(new RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver() {
            @Override
            public void onItemRangeInserted(int positionStart, int itemCount) {
                super.onItemRangeInserted(positionStart, itemCount);
                int friendlyMessageCount = mFirebaseAdapter.getItemCount();
                int lastVisiblePosition =
                        mLinearLayoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
                // If the recycler view is initially being loaded or the
                // user is at the bottom of the list, scroll to the bottom
                // of the list to show the newly added message.
                if (lastVisiblePosition == -1 ||
                        (positionStart >= (friendlyMessageCount - 1) &&
                                lastVisiblePosition == (positionStart - 1))) {
                    mMessageRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(positionStart);
                }
            }
        });

    }






}
```

and my database:

```
{

  "messages" : {

    "ficika3_c" : {
      "1489872857484" : {
        "name" : "c",
        "recipient" : "ficika3",
        "sender" : "c",
        "text" : "gghjj",
        "time" : "1489872857484"
      },
      "1489872859060" : {
        "name" : "c",
        "recipient" : "ficika3",
        "sender" : "c",
        "text" : "hhh",
        "time" : "1489872859060"
      },
      "1489872900098" : {
        "name" : "ficika3",
        "recipient" : "c",
        "sender" : "ficika3",
        "text" : "gghh",
        "time" : "1489872900098"
      },
      "1489873714959" : {
        "name" : "ficika3",
        "recipient" : "c",
        "sender" : "ficika3",
        "text" : "gg",
        "time" : "1489873714959"
      }
    },
       "rokvic_ficika3" : {
      "1489872702555" : {
        "name" : "ficika3",
        "recipient" : "rokvic",
        "sender" : "ficika3",
        "text" : "gghh",
        "time" : "1489872702555"
      },
      "1489872730698" : {
        "name" : "ficika3",
        "recipient" : "rokvic",
        "sender" : "ficika3",
        "text" : "zhj",
        "time" : "1489872730698"
      }
    }

}
```

Comment: There is way more code here than most of us will be willing to mentally debug. You'll have a much better chance of getting help if you [reduce the code to the minimum needed to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (read the link, it is quite useful).